# c++ implementing semaphore on my own

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, semaphore

let's pretend there are no libraries that provide semaphores for C++. I wrote this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

class Semaphore {
    HANDLE mutexS;                  //  provides mutex in semaphore rutines
    std::vector<HANDLE> queue;      //  provides FIFO queue for blocked threads
    int value;                      //  semaphore's value

public:
    Semaphore(int init=1);  
    ~Semaphore();

    void wait();
    void signal();
};


Semaphore::Semaphore(int init) {
    value = init;
    queue = std::vector<HANDLE>();
    mutexS = CreateMutex(0,0,0);
}

Semaphore::~Semaphore() {
    CloseHandle(mutexS);
}




void Semaphore::signal() {
    WaitForSingleObject(mutexS, INFINITE);
    if (++value <= 0) {
        HANDLE someOldThread = queue.front();
        ResumeThread(someOldThread);
        queue.erase(queue.begin());
        CloseHandle(someOldThread);
    }
    ReleaseMutex(mutexS);
}
```

I would like to know why this implementation of wait() doesn't work:

```
void Semaphore::wait() {
    WaitForSingleObject(mutexS, INFINITE);

    if (--value < 0) {
        HANDLE thisThread = GetCurrentThread();   
        queue.push_back(thisThread);
        ReleaseMutex(mutexS);
        SuspendThread(thisThread );
    }
    else
        ReleaseMutex(mutexS);
}
```

And this one works:

```
void Semaphore::wait() {
    WaitForSingleObject(mutexS, INFINITE);

    if (--value < 0) {
        HANDLE thisThread = GetCurrentThread();
        HANDLE alsoThisThread;

        DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), thisThread, GetCurrentProcess(), &alsoThisThread, 0, 0, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

        queue.push_back(alsoThisThread);

        ReleaseMutex(mutexS);

        SuspendThread(alsoThisThread);
    }
    else
        ReleaseMutex(mutexS);
}
```

What exactly happens in each case? I've been banging my head over it for a lot of time now. The first implementation of wait, which doesn't work, makes my program block (well, it probably blocks some thread forever). The 2nd implementation works like a charm. What gives ? Why do I need to duplicate thread handles and block the duplicate ?

Comment: Probably because you call `CloseHandle` in the implementation of `signal()`? I'm not well versed in WinAPI, but it seems only sensible to close a thread when it is finished, not when it is supposed to resume.

Comment: You should also visit codereview later, because your code can definitely be improved a lot.

Comment: No - if I don't CloseHanlde(sameOldThread); the result is the same. That's not it :( Thanks though

Comment: CloseHandle just says "I am not using this handle anymore". Handles in Win32 are reference counted (and for threads and processes, the kernel always holds one of them)

Comment: So yes, calling "CloseHandle" in pair with "DuplicateHandle" is a good thing!

Comment: Not a direct answer to your problem, but a semaphore can be made with a counter, a mutex and a condition variable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Or two mutexes, which is the "canonical" way to do that (http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~jdm/classes/cs550/notes/tech/mutex/semimp3.html)

Comment: Hey Lorenzo, sorry, could you check out the comment made to your solution - I had to edit it, so I am not sure if you saw the follow up. Thanks again!

Comment: If you want a C++ semaphore (assuming one doesn't already exist), why not stick a wrapper around Windows Semaphores? You're already using Windows Mutexes, so if you want a true semaphore, one is already provided. I ask this in case you are writing code for something other than fun and experimentation. If not, ignore me.

Comment: I agree with icabod. You are basing your code on a Win32 [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266.aspx) when you should use a Win32 [semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129.aspx) instead.

Comment: Synchronization objects are a solved problem. A difficult, solved problem. Unless you need this for an exam or something, just don't do it.

Comment: I already implemented this using Win32 semaphores, but I had some issues for unknown reason. I should go back to it and at least figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Alek988Alek: If you had issues when implementing it using Win32 semaphores, then that sounds like an ideal question for SO :)

Comment: SO ??? whats that ? :D

its stack overflow..............................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN helps a lot here ;)

[GetCurrentThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns a pseudo-handle which is a constant for "the current thread":

> A pseudo handle is a special constant that is interpreted as the current thread handle.

So when you push it in the queue, you are always pushing a constant that says "the current thread", which is obviously not what you want.

To get a real handle, you have to use [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> If hSourceHandle is a pseudo handle returned by GetCurrentProcess or GetCurrentThread, DuplicateHandle converts it to a real handle to a process or thread, respectively.

A final note: I suppose you are implementing this as a "test" right? Because there are several potential problems.. A very good learning exercise would be to dig them out. But you should not use this in production code.

Out of curiosity: if you want to experiment a little more, the "canonical" way of implementing semaphore with mutexes is to use two mutexes: [see here](http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~jdm/classes/cs550/notes/tech/mutex/semimp3.html)

Comment: I read the documentation twice. I guess I was tired... Thanks!!

This is workaround to some other problem. Could you please point out the flaws you see with this? I don't think I'll ever write something like this again - but I'd like to know. Thanks!

Comment: The link stefaanv provided (or the other implementation I linked) are good starting points; I personally do not like very much the manual pause thread/resume thread logic. Another thread may "resume" the sleeping thread by calling the function (all it has to do is to get a handle)

Comment: You may also try to make it recursive: what if a thread acquires the same semaphore twice? (usually, the second acquire succeeds).

Comment: I see - so it is sensitive to abuse. It will not pose a problem in my solution (its a school project, nobody will abuse it that much :D ) - but its good to know this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem ;)
You may also want to look at a nice article on MSDN mag (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163642.aspx) (Mutex-based semaphores usually require a fair mutex, and Win32 mutexes are not precisely fair)

Comment: What if a thread acquires the semaphore twice? What can be a problem there? Could you elaborate please ?

Comment: My advice is to look at this (excellent) blog: http://preshing.com/20120305/implementing-a-recursive-mutex/
In your case: 2-res semaphore. Both threads gets a resource, counter is decremented. They ask for the lock again. They are both waiting, suspended, and no-one releases the lock.

Comment: Isn't that secured via mutexS ?

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN documentation for GetCurrentThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683182.aspx) has the answer (accents are mine):

> The return value is a **pseudo handle** for the current thread.
>
> A pseudo handle is **a special constant that is interpreted as the current thread handle**. The calling thread can use this handle to specify itself whenever a thread handle is required.
>
> ...
>
> The function cannot be used by one thread to create a handle that can be used by other threads to refer to the first thread. **The handle is always interpreted as referring to the thread that is using it**. A thread can create a "real" handle to itself that can be used by other threads, or inherited by other processes, by specifying the pseudo handle as the source handle in a call to the DuplicateHandle function.

Comment: I read the documentation twice. I guess I was tired... Thanks!!